# Using sed transliterate command in python

Tags: python-3.x, sed, ascii, fastq

So there is this sed command that allows you to transform the quality code in ASCII into bar symbols:

```
sed -e 'n;n;n;y/!"#$%&'\''()*+,-.\/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKL/▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▂▂▂▂▃▃▃▃▃▄▄▄▄▄▅▅▅▅▅▆▆▆▆▆▇▇▇▇▇██████/' myfile.fastq
```

I have been checking ways to do the same in python, but I have not found a solution I can use. Maybe pysed or re.sub, but I do not even know how to write the ASCII code in a string without python getting mixed up the characters.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please use code tags as per Rules for your commands and samples, thanks.

Comment: Isn't python3 sed ascii and fastq enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to transliterate characters in the 3rd line of your [FASTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) file?

You can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) on translation table built with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
lut = str.maketrans('''!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKL''',
                    '''▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▂▂▂▂▃▃▃▃▃▄▄▄▄▄▅▅▅▅▅▆▆▆▆▆▇▇▇▇▇██████''')

with open('/path/to/fastq') as f:
    line3 = f.readlines()[3].strip()

print(line3.translate(lut))
```

For a sample file from Wikipedia:

```
@SEQ_ID
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
+
!''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65
```

the Python script above will produce:

```
▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▁▁▂▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▂▃▃▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▁▂▂▂▂▄▄▇▇▇▆▆▆▆▆▆▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▄▄
```

---

However, note that according to [FASTQ format description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format#Format), your translation table is incorrect. The character `!` represents the lowest quality while `~` is the highest (not `L` as you have).

Also note that quality value characters directly map the ASCII character range `!`-`~` to the quality value. In other words, we can build the translation table programmatically:

```
span = ord('█') - ord('▁') + 1
src = ''.join(chr(c) for c in range(ord('!'), ord('~')+1))
dst = ''.join(chr(ord('▁') + span*(ord(c)-ord('!'))//len(src)) for c in src)
lut = str.maketrans(src, dst)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have to read a bit on chr, ord and maketrans to fully understand why it works, but it does work in my script.